# Where do memories come from?

Tags: torah-study, mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism, chabad, psychology

BH

Where do Memories come from?

I was told that they come from the chochma power of the soul being translated in Bina I believe. Is this true if yes how and where does it talk more about this?

Answer (score 4):

I would point you to a Rabbeinu Yona, not so well known, that does give you something to work with (though he does not get so specific with the terminology as you have).

> כי טבע הגוף משכח וכי יעשה האיש דבר כיעור ויתבייש עליו מבני אדם לשנה או לשנתיים ישכח הדבר וילך הבושה מעליו וגם כי לא ישכח מלבו. יהיה הדבר ישן נושן והוסרה קצת הבושה כי טבע השכחה שבגוף מתערב עם טבע הנפש וכי אינו יכול להתגבר עליו לשכוח הדבר לגמרי על כל פנים יתגבר עליו להתיישן הדבר שהוא קצת השכחה שמסיר רוב הבושה. אך בהיות הנפש לבדה אין שכחה לפניה כי כלה ברה וזכה ואין שום טבע מהגשמים בתוכה.

He says that memory is the status quo of our spiritual existence, and the real question is where does forgetting come from. This is a bodily function which will be abandoned in the world to come (with frightening consequences, see the rest of the quote [inside](https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Yonah_on_Pirkei_Avot.3.1?lang=bi)...)

Also significant is what I have heard in the name of Rav Yitzchak Hutner (author of Pachad Yitzchak), that forgetfulness is the decree of death on knowledge (while physical death is the decree on the body). Hard to know how he develops that without seeing it inside, which I have not.